# How can I modify a set of vectors to have the same size?

Tags: matlab

i'm trying to extract HOG_features for mathematical symbols classification (i will use SVM classifier). I get a 1xn vector then i have to put all the vectors in a single matrix. The problem is that the size of the feature vector is different for each image so I can't concatenate them.
Is there a way to make all vectors having the same size ?
Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```matlab
rep1 = 'D:\mémoire MASTER\data';
ext = '*.tif' ;

chemin = fullfile(rep1, ext);
list = dir(chemin);
for i=1:length(list)
    I = imread(fullfile(rep1, list(i).name), ext(3:end));
    if size(I,3)==3 % RGB image
        I = rgb2gray(I);
    end
    I1 = imbinarize(I);

    % Extract HOG features data
    HOG_feat = extractHOGFeatures(I1,'CellSize', [2 2]);
    HOG_feat1 = HOG_feat';
end
```

Comment: Do you need a matrix? you can use cell arrays for this

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, please [edit] this one to more clearly explain what you want. Also please address Ander's comment, as this smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/325771); probably there is a much better solution for your problem than concatenating vectors. Please describe the problem and why this code does not work for that, and you'll get much more meaningful answers

Comment: the two questions are not the same. The problem of modifying the size of the vectors is solved, now i have all the feature vectors with the same size.
even though i can't concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can pad each one with zeros to be as long as the longest one:

e.g. to put two vectors, v1 and v2, into a matrix M:

```
M = zeros(2,max(length(v1),length(v2)));
M(1,1:length(v1)) = v1;
M(2,1:length(v2)) = v2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem that all your vectors are a different size. Instead of trying to coerce them to be the sesame size by zero-padding or interpolating (both I think are bad ideas), change your computation so that the length of the output vector does not depend on the size of the image.

This is your current code:

```
HOG_feat = extractHOGFeatures(I1,'CellSize', [2 2]);
           %                                  ^^^
           % the image is split in cells of 2x2 pixels
```

2x2 cells are way too small for this method anyway. You could instead divide your image into a set number of cells, say 100 cells:

```
cellSize = ceil(size(I1)/10);
HOG_feat = extractHOGFeatures(I1,'CellSize', cellSize);
```

(I’m using `ceil` in the division because I figure it’s necessary to have an integer size. But I’m not sure whether `ceil` or `floor` or `round` is needed here, and I don’t have access to this function to test it. A bit of trial and error should show which method gives consistent output size.)